# SpringExtension without an explicit configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-test

I have a JUnit5 test with `SpringExtension`. All I need is environment variables to be injected via Spring's `@Value`:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class MyTest {
    @Value("${myValue}") String myValue;
    ...
```

Doing so, I get an error saying:

> Failed to load ApplicationContext Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither GenericGroovyXmlContextLoader nor AnnotationConfigContextLoader was able to load an ApplicationContext

Of course, Spring needs to have a context configuration, so I put it into the test code:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration
class MyTest {
    @Value("${myValue}") String myValue;

    @Configuration
    static class TestConfig { /*empty*/ }
    ...
```

While this works, it looks like a lot of unnecessary boilerplate code to me. Is there a simpler way?

**UPDATE**

One shorter variant would be to use `@SpringJUnitConfig` which brings both `@ContextConfiguration` and `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` out of the box.

But a configuration class (even an empty one) is still needed.

Comment: The idea of a the `SpringExtension` is that you are using beans from a context in the test. If you don't need that then why bother with the `SpringExtension` in the first place? Just use `System.getenv` if they are real environment values or `System.getProperty` instead of `@Value`.

Comment: M. Deinum: Because with `@Value` I don't have to care about from which source my properties come. Or I can use `@TestPropertySource` in my test, which is pretty handy. My question is about how to get rid of the empty config.

Comment: You cannot... As that is assumed by running a test with Spring. You are trying to use it for something it isn't designed for. Also making unit tests dependend on environment variables is probably also something you don't want to do.

Comment: M.Deinum: "You cannot..." What? Why? This works perfectly fine... I have nothing agains running with Spring, actually this is exactly I want. I'm just looking for a shortcut for the empty configuration.

Comment: As stated you cannot as the context framework (the Spring Test Context framework) expect an application context, which needs a configuration. So you cannot do that without a configuration, unless you write your own custom `ContextLoader` which creates an partially empty application context. Which is more of a hassle then writing an empty configuration.

Comment: Definitely, that's why I was asking about any already existing solution. Obviously, there is none. Thank you for the clarification. If you put this into an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run a Spring based test without a configuration. The Spring Test Context Framework (TCF) expects/requires an `ApplicationContext`. To create an `ApplicationContext` a form configuration (xml, Java) needs to be present.

You have 2 options to make it work

1. Use an empty configuration, emtpy XML file or empty `@Configuration` class
2. Write a custom [`ContextLoader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ContextLoader.html) which creates an empty application context.

Option 1 is probably the easiest to achieve. You could create a global empty configuration and refer that from the `@ContextConfiguration`.

Answer (score 2):

As has been pointed out in other answers and comments, you need to specify an empty configuration source, specifically a `@Configuration` class, XML config file, Groovy config file, or `ApplicationContextInitializer`.

The easiest way to do that is to create your own *composed annotation* that predefines the empty configuration.

If you introduce the following `@EmptySpringJUnitConfig` annotation in your project, you can use it (instead of `@SpringJUnitConfig`) wherever you want an empty Spring `ApplicationContext`.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Documented
@Inherited
@SpringJUnitConfig(EmptySpringJUnitConfig.Config.class)
public @interface EmptySpringJUnitConfig {
    @Configuration
    class Config {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This is exactly what I did for my project and I was just wondering if there is already a similar standard solution for this.

Comment: No, there is not a "standard" solution for this, since this is typically not a good practice. As mentioned elsewhere, you typically should not need an empty `ApplicationContext`.

Answer (score 0):

In SpringBoot to run a spring application context, you need to use the `@SpringBootTest` annotation on the test class:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
class MyTest {
    @Value("${myValue}") String myValue;
    ...
```

**UPDATED:**

Or if you use just a Spring Framework (without spring boot) then test configuration depends on a version of the spring framework which you use, and on the spring configuration of your project.

You can set configuration files by the using of @ContextConfiguration, if you use java config then it will be something like that:

```java
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class MyTest {
    ...
```

or if you use xml configuration:

```java
@ContextConfiguration("/test-config.xml")
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class MyTest {
    ...
```

both of these depends on your project configuration structure and list of beans which you need in tests.

More details about context configuration: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#spring-testing-annotation-contextconfiguration

If you use the Spring Framework older then 5.0 then you can find useful this library: https://github.com/sbrannen/spring-test-junit5

Comment: I don't want to use `@SpringBootTest`, my application is spring-boot free.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but both suggestions need a configuration (`AppConfig.class` or `test-config.xml`), because my test doesn't need any, I have to create an empty one, which I find unhappy. That is what is my question about.